# Accept custom header field "Content type" in apache

Tags: apache-2.4, 400, bad-request

My app was sending request with header field `"Content type"` [sic] and value `"form-data"` [sic] to the server. Although it seems wrong - it seems it was causing no problem until couple of days ago. Then something happened (admin installed security update or so) and now the lamp server returns `400 bad request`, which is what one would expect.

While I could update the app to send proper header values but I'm not allowed to due to client's requirement - and I need to be able to revert / accept the bad request as it was working before.

With any other server it seems it would work fine - but on my server and local machine - the app now gets `400 bad request` returned.

Any idea how I could make this work? I think the server admin installed some security update and this problem appeared but I don't seem to be able to revert it in any way. Even creating a new server isn't solving it.

I've seen some module `'mod_headers'` for apache which I think might be able to allow me to accept a custom malformed header `"Content type"` but not sure if that is the way to go.

This is all that I'm getting in my local machines server log (screenshot of access log):

[image]

Comment: whos the client? The server owner?

Comment: @JIV excuse me for the poorly worded description. i developed the app for a client. i own the server. client doesn't want/can't update the app due to his own reasons. so i need the existing app with malformed request to work with the server like it was working before. i can make any/all changes to the server, not the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you conform to standards?

RFC 7230, HTTP/1.1 Message Syntax and Routing,  [section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2):

> 3.2.  Header Fields
>
> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name
> followed    by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field
> value, and    optional trailing whitespace.
>
> ```
>  header-field   = `field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS`
> ```

If it was working, it was wrong. Update your app to use standard HTTP/1.1 `Content-Type: type/subtype` header providing a standard MIME type, instead. Then, you don't need any workarounds or hacks to get your web server work against standards.